# Is there a way to add pre-build step for Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, pre-build-event, prebuild

Currently I'm able to use a post directive in my Jenkinsfile. Is there a way to trigger a pre-build step similar to this ?

```
  post {
    always {
      sh '''rm -rf build/workspace'''
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can't you just make your first stage the pre step?

Comment: Actually I'm trying to add a skip ci step. It works for pull requests but it does not work main branches like a direct commit to master even has '[ci skip]' it's still being triggered. -> https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Commit+Skip+SCM+Behaviour+Plugin

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to run a pre-checkout step in declarative Jenkins pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348629/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-pre-checkout-step-in-declarative-jenkins-pipelines)

Answer (score 7):

I believe this newer question may have the answer: [Is there a way to run a pre-checkout step in declarative Jenkins pipelines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45348629/is-there-a-way-to-run-a-pre-checkout-step-in-declarative-jenkins-pipelines)

> pre is a cool feature idea, but doesn't exist yet. skipDefaultCheckout
>   and checkout scm (which is the same as the default checkout) are the
>   keys:
>
> ```
> pipeline {
>   agent { label 'docker' }
>   options {
>     skipDefaultCheckout true
>   }
>   stages {
>     stage('clean_workspace_and_checkout_source') {
>       steps {
>         deleteDir()
>         checkout scm
>       }
>     }
>     stage('build') {
>       steps {
>         echo 'i build therefore i am'
>       }
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: I'm looking for the same concept. But the problem here is that I want to perform a task even previous agent docker is setup on the master server. With this method the "pre-task" will be run inside docker

Comment: you should be able to declare actions on a seperate node for certain steps using
node('master') {
      steps {
        doSomething()
      }
}